# La API de YouTube no me detecta el evento de play

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

¿Por qué el evento de play de mi video no es detectado? quiero que al reproducir el video, una declaración se active, pero no pasa nada ¿dónde está el error?

este es el reproductor con el video

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ntjjEzhr1wc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

El enlace de la Api

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

El codigo de la API

```
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'ntjjEzhr1wc',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("event detected");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No estás definiendo la función `onPlayerReady`, por ejemplo: **`function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); }`** [Revisa la doc de la API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es-419).

Comment: @A.Cedano sí lei la documentacion, no incluí `function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();}` porque había un comentario ahi que decía que esa funcion se activa cuando el reproductor esta listo, no sirve para detectar eventos del reproductor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación de la API es clara al respecto.

1. Necesitas crear un `div`  con `id="player"` donde se cargará el iframe desde `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`. Este `div` puede tener otro id, pero debe coincidir con lo que indiques en la función antes citada.
2. Te falta crear la función `onPlayerReady()` que será llamada por la API cuando el reproductor esté listo.

Así debería funcionar:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'ntjjEzhr1wc',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            console.log("event detected");
        }
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) { 
        event.target.playVideo(); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionó, sin duda la documentacion no explica nada bien, tu respuesta sirvió.

Comment: Me olvidaba, me funcionó sin necesidad poner el div, solo añadir la ultima función

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu ejemplo no va a funcionar ya es necesaria la función [onPlayerReady](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es) , la cual es llamada por la API cuando el video está listo para reproducir.

> La función  [`onPlayerReady`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es)  se ejecuta cuando se activa el evento
> onReady. En este ejemplo, la función indica que la reproducción debe
> comenzar cuando el reproductor de video está listo.

únicamente necesitas agregar esta función para que tu ejemplo funcione:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
```

Este es un ejemplo completo que reproduce un video usando [YouTube Player API para iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Android Iframe integration</title>
    <!--YouTube.com/iframe_api tag-->
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script>

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'C-OH9yU6-pY',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }   

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            console.log("event detected");
        }
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) { 
        event.target.playVideo(); 
    }

</script>
<body>
    <hr>
        <!-- Si tiene más de un vídeo de YouTube en la página, Crea un div diferente para cada player. -->
        <div id="player"></div>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Jorgesys YouTube API de IFrame]